# How can I add script tags to my draftjs editor?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I've started building a rich text editor with DraftJS and have made decent progress. Now I am stuck on adding embedded content. I tried manually adding script tags by editing html separately and calling convertFromHTML with the new html, but that did not work.

I would like to add content like gists to my rich text editor, but am not sure how.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom block component: https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-block-components.html#custom-block-components

> Within the Editor component, one may specify the blockRendererFn prop.
>   This prop function allows a higher-level component to define custom
>   React rendering for ContentBlock objects, based on block type, text,
>   or other criteria.
>
> For instance, we may wish to render ContentBlock objects of type
>   'atomic' using a custom MediaComponent.
>
> ```
> function myBlockRenderer(contentBlock) {
>   const type = contentBlock.getType();
>   if (type === 'atomic') {
>     return {
>       component: MediaComponent,
>       editable: false,
>       props: {
>         foo: 'bar',
>       },
>     };
>   }
> }
>
> // Then...
> import {Editor} from 'draft-js';
> class EditorWithMedia extends React.Component {
>   ...
>   render() {
>     return <Editor ... blockRendererFn={myBlockRenderer} />;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> If no custom renderer object is returned by the blockRendererFn
>   function, Editor will render the default DraftEditorBlock text block
>   component.
>
> The component property defines the component to be used, while the
>   optional props object includes props that will be passed through to
>   the rendered custom component via the props.blockProps sub property
>   object. In addition, the optional editable property determines whether
>   the custom component is contentEditable.
>
> It is strongly recommended that you use editable: false if your custom
>   component will not contain text.
>
> If your component contains text as provided by your ContentState, your
>   custom component should compose a DraftEditorBlock component. This
>   will allow the Draft framework to properly maintain cursor behavior
>   within your contents.
>
> By defining this function within the context of a higher-level
>   component, the props for this custom component may be bound to that
>   component, allowing instance methods for custom component props.
>
> ### Defining custom block components
>
> Within MediaComponent, the most likely use case is that you will want to retrieve entity metadata to
>   render your custom block. You may apply an entity key to the text
>   within a 'atomic' block during EditorState management, then retrieve
>   the metadata for that key in your custom component render() code.
>
> ```
> class MediaComponent extends React.Component {
>   render() {
>     const {block, contentState} = this.props;
>     const {foo} = this.props.blockProps;
>     const data = contentState.getEntity(block.getEntityAt(0)).getData();
>     // Return a <figure> or some other content using this data.
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The ContentBlock object and the ContentState record are made available
>   within the custom component, along with the props defined at the top
>   level. By extracting entity information from the ContentBlock and the
>   Entity map, you can obtain the metadata required to render your custom
>   component.
>
> *Retrieving the entity from the block is admittedly a bit of an awkward
>   API, and is worth revisiting.*

Answer (score 0):

Basically Mike's answer is the solution. We had similar need days before and we created the following plugin https://github.com/jimmycodesocial/draft-js-iframely-plugin

PD: It uses the iframely.com service (but you can adapt it to your needs).